# reactjs - is there anyway to add delay to onclick event on mobie?

Tags: reactjs

I display a list of item in my website. When a user clicks on the item, the website will display data of item. There are a lot of item so I can use my mouse to scroll up and down to view all items in my laptop.

However, in my phone, its screen is small and I have to use my finger to scroll up and down. when I tap on the screen to scroll, my finger is over the item and its content is displayed.

So is there anyway to add delay to onclick event or other solutions to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I don't think a delay will solve your problem since it's going to trigger the click handler anyways. Unless this is exactly what you want to do, you can use the `debouce` function from lodash for example. You simply specify how long it takes to trigger you click and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added debouce event with 500 ms delay to onScroll event but quite strange, the debouce event only be executed after 1-2 seconds. so Do you have any idea about this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you have a list of items and whenever you click you "expand" them so you can display some more information about them. Why not remove this click handler and instead add a "Show more" button on each item and then open the details you want to show?